# Hyperledger Multinode setup

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to setup a blockchain network using 4 vms. each of the vms has fabric-peer and fabric-membersrvc docker images and that seems to work successfully. I have setup password less ssh among all vms for normal user(non-root). But the docker images are unable to communicate with each other.

Do I require Passwordless ssh for "root" users among vms ? Are there any other requirements?

Answer (score 1):

the membersrvc docker image is not required on all VMs. currently (v0.6) there can be only 1 membersrvc.

if all your peers are docker containers, they talk to eachother via their advertised address, which you can set through environment variable when you start the peer containers:

```
-e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=<ip of docker host>:7051"
```

make sure you don't use the ip of the container because you don't have a swarm cluster running (for overlay networking) so the containers on the other hosts cannot talk to the private ip of containers on other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get peers running in docker to talk to each other:

- Make sure that the grpc ports are mapped from the docker VM to the
  host
- Set the CORE_PEER_ADDRESS to `<IP of host running docker>:<grpc
  port>`
- Make sure you use the IP of the host for the grpc communication
  addresses such as membersrvc address, discovery root node etc.